# jQuery search matching string and remove parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've an HTML below:

```
<div id="keywords">
    <div id="container0">
        <span id="term010"> this</span>
        <span id="term111"> is</span>
        <span id="term212"> a</span>
        <span id="term313"> phrase</span>
    </div>

    <div id="container1">
        <span id="term014"> exact</span>
        <span id="term115"> match</span>
        <span id="term216"> type</span>
    </div>

    <div id="container2">
        <span id="term017"> this</span>
        <span id="term118"> is</span>
        <span id="term219"> a</span>
        <span id="term320"> broad</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I would like to remove the parent DIV (container) and it's content if a child span contains a word, "this" for example.
The code should search for the word "this" on all spans and delete the divs with the Id "container0" and "container2". I already have the Regex but I'm totally lost after that. I know that I should use querySelector but I never used it before and tried to make it work, but I failed.

```
/\<span id="term[0-9]{3,}"> this<\/span>/gm
```

Thank you,

Comment: I stumbled back on this question just now. You should change the accepted the answer from mine to the one from @LouysPatriceBessette since it looks like that answer was the most helpful to you (I think you can change the accepted answer anytime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are looking for with jquery by doing something like the following (since you mentioned `querySelector`, you should know that it can be done with plain javascript as well - see the second code example below).

JQuery:

```js
const spans = $('span');
spans.each(function(index, elem) {
  if (elem.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf('this') >= 0) {
    elem.parentNode.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="keywords">
  <div id="container0">
    <span id="term010"> this</span>
    <span id="term111"> is</span>
    <span id="term212"> a</span>
    <span id="term313"> phrase</span>
  </div>
  <div id="container1">
    <span id="term014"> exact</span>
    <span id="term115"> match</span>
    <span id="term216"> type</span>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    <span id="term017"> this</span>
    <span id="term118"> is</span>
    <span id="term219"> a</span>
    <span id="term320"> broad</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript only:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
for (const span of spans) {
  if (span.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf('this') >= 0) {
    span.parentNode.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="keywords">
  <div id="container0">
    <span id="term010"> this</span>
    <span id="term111"> is</span>
    <span id="term212"> a</span>
    <span id="term313"> phrase</span>
  </div>
  <div id="container1">
    <span id="term014"> exact</span>
    <span id="term115"> match</span>
    <span id="term216"> type</span>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    <span id="term017"> this</span>
    <span id="term118"> is</span>
    <span id="term219"> a</span>
    <span id="term320"> broad</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HiThank you for your help. Sorry for the delay, but I had to challenge the code to see if it works as intended in my code. I've found that if I use "this is" the code stops working because the two words are in separate spans so matching would impossible with the code as is, my bad. The words should be present in the div but they should also be next to each other. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your question has changed from removing the parent div when a span contains a specific matching word to removing the parent div when the words contained in sibling spans match a sequence of words entered by a user. This is doable but would be helpful if you either edit your question with the specifics of what you are looking for or post another question. Consider whether each word inside the container divs really needs to be contained in a span (because there are different approaches depending on how you structure your html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:contain()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#keywords").find("span:contains('this')").each(function(){
    if($(this).next("span").html()==" is"){  // Watch out for leading space!!!
      $(this).parent("div").remove();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="keywords">
    <div id="container0">
        <span id="term010"> this</span>
        <span id="term111"> is</span>
        <span id="term212"> a</span>
        <span id="term313"> phrase</span>
    </div>

    <div id="container1">
        <span id="term014"> this</span>
        <span id="term014"> deserves</span>
        <span id="term014"> exact</span>
        <span id="term115"> match</span>
        <span id="term216"> type</span>
    </div>

    <div id="container2">
        <span id="term017"> this</span>
        <span id="term118"> is</span>
        <span id="term219"> a</span>
        <span id="term320"> broad</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works as intended, Do you have any idea how to remove the div id if the word matched is "this is" and not just "this"? This is my concern actually. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: mmm.. I don't think there is a full-proof way for that, except to define all the exlusions... May be a pain. But is possible using `.not()`. I edited.

Comment: Thank you again, but this won't work. In fact, my script allows the user to choose the words (one or more in each line) he wants to remove in the DIV, hence each word in a separate span.

Comment: Ha... So you need to target a combinaison like `<span>this</span>` followed by `<span>is</span>`... ok hold on.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It should also work if the user chooses just one word.

Comment: Okay... Here it is... The trick is to look for the `.next()` element's text. ;) And if user choses just one word... The second will be `""`(empty)... So the rule should work anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. this helps a lot. I have a lot to work on starting here, as the user may choose more than 2 words, but it's a good start.

Comment: I'm glad it helped... What you do is the kind of puzzle strategy I like. Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks again from a fellow Quebecer ;)